# iOS: Grouped UITableView issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4, grouped-table

When I try to change the table view style from *Plain* to *Grouped* in the attribute inspector and then build, it gives me the following error message: *Uncategorized could not read archive*. So what's the problem?

Comment: I tried to create a new project, however the same problem still exist.

Comment: I have found out what's the problem!

When I changed the *Group Table View Background Color*, the project compiled without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not using any special character in your project name or any where else? 
Because i have created one project in Xcode 4 and then grouped tableview using attributes and run the programme and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I'm sure I have never used any special character in the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

all your xib files and classes should not contain special charecters like $,#,% etc search and remove them

Comment: All my classes and nib files' names don't contain any special characters.